# Extracting Data from Siebel Database to Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, siebel, vba

I want to fetch data from Siebel Database to an excel workbook and it should refresh whenever it is loaded. I know we can do it with SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL but not sure about the connection parameters for Siebel while coding it in Excel-VBA. Any reference to the context would be helpful.

Comment: maybe https://it.toolbox.com/blogs/joshuaweir/example-siebel-scripting-through-ms-excel-siebel-com-data-server-090708 could help

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Siebel database". Siebel applications use an external database (typically Oracle, but it's not the only one they support). You can either connect directly to that database (which you said you know how), or you can access the data through Siebel interfaces such as the COM Data Control (a good starting point for that would be the link provided by DaDirnbocher)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to want to use the REST or SOAP functionality in siebel and then on the VBA side use the appropriate library to ingest the data.

REST
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E74890_01/books/PDF/RestAPI.pdf

SOAP
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12103_01/books/PDF/AnyWebServ.pdf

I know VBA can use either but I dont code in it so you are gonna wanna google for how to use APIs.